# make Kile default for tex files

Tags: 12.04, text-editor, kile

I re-installed Ubuntu due to some issues but before the re-install, I was able to make my default tex editor by going into properties, other apps, and selecting Kile.

Now Kile isn't an option to select.  What can I do?